# Issues defining urls in xcconfig file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcconfig

I'm trying to use `xcconfig` file to create different configurations for development, qa & production versions of my application. I've different api end-points for those 3 environment, so I've defined that value in my config file like:

```
api_url = https://api-qa.mydomain.com
```

But when I read back, I only get `https:` the remaining part will be taken as a comment and won't be treated as part of the string.

**Approach 1:**

```
api_url = "https://api-qa.mydomain.com"
```

**Result 1:**

```
\"https://api-qa.mydomain.com\"
```

---

**Approach 2:**

```
api_url = api-qa.mydomain.com
```

**Result 2:**

It gave me back what I've defined (`api-qa.mydomain.com`) and I'm prefixing `https://` in front of this result in my code.

---

Is there any clean way to define my API url in the config file? I don't want to prefix http or https in my code (My dev runs on http & qa and production runs on https, I don't want to change it in code each and every time when I change my environment). Any help would be much appreciated

Additional resource I've referred: https://help.apple.com/xcode/#/dev745c5c974

Comment: Did you try percent encoded url string?

Answer (score 0):

How about two entries, `api_host` and `api_scheme`? You could then build the URL based on these two values, either with string concatenation, or via the `URLComponents` structure.